# Use array in jQuery to populate page

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

It sounds so simple but somehow it doesn't work.

I have a template page that should be updated using long polling. I have the long polling working but I fail at processing/inserting the data.

This is the HTML part:

```
<p><b><div id="weather">weather here</div></b></p>
<p><div id="temperature">temperature here</div></p>
<p><i><div id="color">color here</div></i></p>
```

This is the script:

```
var obj = {
    "color": "#880000",
        "temperature": "hot",
        "weather": "cloudy"
};

$.each(obj function (key,value) {
    ('#key').html('value');
});
```

Additionally, I would like to use the color in my style sheet but I can't figure out how to replace a non-*div*ed Element:

```
#color {
    color: #880000
}
```

I thought the *each* array iteration is from the textbook. What am I missing?
([jfsiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/SKssF/150/))

---

**Second attempt** based on what was suggested, now the bigger picture which gives a type error:

php file (array_2.php):

```
<?php
/*
Values get read from files.
Here, in the example, we simply populate variables.

Original: 
$color = file_get_contents('/path/to/txt/file/with/value');
*/ 
$color = "#880000";
$temperature = "hot";
$weather = "cloudy";
$items = array(array(id => 'weather', text => $weather), array(id => 'color', text => $color), array(id => 'temperature', text => $temperature),);  
echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

html/javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Satus Poller</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       function addstatus(obj){
        $.each(obj, function (key,value) {
            $('#' + value.id).html(value.text);
        });
    };
    function waitForMsg(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "array_2.php",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000,

            success: function(data){
                var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
                var obj = arr + ""; /* This doesn't help */
                addstatus(obj);
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg,
                    1000
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg,
                    15000);
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        waitForMsg();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><div id="color">color</div></p>
    <p><div id="temperature">temperature</div></p>
    <p><div id="weather">weather</div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

(I haven't even tried to approach replacing text and CSS elements at the same time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's approach was correct, but with a couple of typos.

```
var obj = {
  "color": "#880000",
  "temperature": "hot",
  "weather": "cloudy"
};

// missing $, or jQuery
$.each(obj, function (key,value) {
  // missing comma

  $('#'+key).html(value);
  // variable key and value wrapped inside quote
});
```

Comment: I seem to be running in a conflict when using this approach in my more elaborate script: "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj". I will need to give it some rest and look around for a solution for this.

Comment: @PiEnthusiast I can't help if you don't show the complete code.

Comment: Solved my last problem. The solution was to declare the data provided by the PHP part as content-type: */json:
`header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: I have a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463177/insert-text-attributes-and-paths-on-condition).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/SKssF/151/

I changed this to an array so that it can foreach over, indicated by square brackets []

```
var obj = [
    {id:"color", text:"#880000"},
    {id:"temperature", text:"hot"},
    {id:"weather", text: "cloudy"}
];
```

You were missing a comma next to the `obj, function`, missing the jquery selector `$`.  `'#key'` is just string and javascript had no idea you meant the variable:

```
$.each(obj, function (key,value) {
    $('#' + value.id).html(value.text);
});
```

Comment: I don't think obj must be an array... its content is used to fill a template that I suppose (cause use css id) is not repeated in the page

Comment: It might actually use the data on several places of the page, I am not sure yet.